# How to add a version number to war file in web application development?

Tags: versioning, pom.xml

I am a beginar of m2e application development by using eclipse(kepler) and my server is jboss 7.1.1 final.I have two war files,one is for client and second is for server .I have an url pattern such as  "myproject.com".Now my question is  I want to access the data which is present in server war file even I made a changes i.e  added the version number to war file for example "Server.war" to "Server0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" by using pom.xml file of my project.Would you please explain me what are the changes I need to do in my pom.xml file.

Thanks in advance,
Prasad

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to keep the same web context despite the war file's name or whatever... In Jboss AS7 you can set the war's context root using the jboss-web.xml [deployment descriptor](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Deployment+Descriptors+used+In+AS7.1). Just create the file into *your_war/WEB-INF* folder with this content,

```
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>Server.war</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

With maven you can package/install the war using a custom name and concat the version number if you want.
Set a custom name using `<finalName>` tag inside the *build* section, for example:

```
<finalName>ServerAnotherName-${project.version}</finalName>
```

Removing the tag, the [default name](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#The_Super_POM) will be `${project.artifactId}-${project.version}`

Comment: For welcome! But don't need to be graceful just accept the answer to show everyone else correct solution :)